# MasterPage Concept in Winforms DevExpress?

Tags: winforms, devexpress

Actually,I am new to Winforms.
Is there any thing like MasterPage Concept in Winforms DevExpress ?
Is this Possible through InheritedForms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible in Winforms although it has nothing to do with Devex.

What you can do is create a form and call it `MasterForm` and then every additional form you create - can inherit from it.

Check out this link [Inherited Forms](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_inherited_forms.html) for more info and examples :)